# How to repair and clean alternator

Tags: electrical, alternator, repair

My car won't start and it's because power steering pump slings oil on it. I was told that I had to clean it to be able to have it charge. I need to know if I clean my alternator from all that sludge will it save it?

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of question that is hard to answer, there are so many possibilities and they depend on the amount and type of sludge and the specific alternator and the phase of the moon and how long the sludge has been there and on and on. If the source who suggested cleaning it seems credible, then your odds are better…

It is possible that the alternator was damaged by either heat build up due to the sludge or that the sludge is conductive and has shorted it out damaging the regulator and/or rectifier or maybe the windings themselves.

On the other hand it is almost certainly worth a try. I'd be tempted to read the answers mentioned in the comment and do some searches then try some of the techniques suggested. I don't think they would be too difficult or expensive – almost certainly less than a new alternator.